# Increase number of channel entries displayed in control panel

Tags: control-panel, entries

A few years back, I worked on a client EE project that involved deleting thousands of existing entries. A fellow EE developer showed me that you could append the query string with a variable that will tell EE to display more than just the standard 50 entries.

```
http://domain.com/admin.php?D=cp&C=content_edit&{mystery_variable}=200
```

I remember using it, and it being a lifesaver, but I've forgotten what the actual variable is, and have had no luck searching for it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending this

```
&perpage=1000
```

Comment: That's the ticket! I had tried several variations, like per_page (which is actually in the EE pagination spec), but the underscore-free version was the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of using Zoo Visitor. This has a limit parameter. In reality it is dealing with entries connected to member account and does the member deletion based on deleting the entry.

The limit parameter doesn't seem to work on the members list.

Comment: No, this was a native EE function.